# I can't access a derived class method that is instantiated in an array

Tags: c#, derived-class

I was testing with some code and occasionally I can't access a method that is in a derived class.What could I be doing wrong?

```cs
namespace Example
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            A[] test = new A[2];
            test[0] = new B();
            test[0].Example();
            test[0].Example1();
        }
        public class A
        {
            public void Example()
            {

            }
        }
        class B : A
        {
            public void Example1()
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The static type of array is A[], not B[]. Unless you downcast each element, conditionally, you will not be able to access Example1(). That, or make it a virtual method in A.

Comment: @TanveerBadar - I think it's misleading to say "static type" - you should simply just say "type".

Comment: The type at runtime would be B for that element, however compile time type is A. It is not misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast it to B type like this:

```
namespace Example
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            A[] test = new A[2];
            test[0] = new B();
            test[0].Example();
            (test[0] as B).Example1();
        }
        public class A
        {
            public void Example()
            {

            }
        }
        class B : A
        {
            public void Example1()
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to learn more about casting check the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions).

Edit: Casting works in this case because test[0] is of type B, if that wasn't the case the expression (test[0] as B) will return null which causes a NullReferenceException and means that test[0] cannot be casted to the type B.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning in your answer that if `test[0]` isn't a `B`, you'll get a `NullReferenceException` (since `X as Y` returns `default(Y)` - for reference types this means `null` - if `X` can't be cast to `Y`)